# Having trouble fulling understanding object iteration with a For-In loop

Tags: javascript, loops, object, iteration, for-in-loop

guys. First off, thanks to all who are taking their time to help a guy out. I'm currently going through object iteration with a for-in and right now, I'm having a bit of trouble trying to print out the string object the way I really want it to. Here's an example I'm working with.

I have a variable that looks something like this.

```
var someString = 'This is a string object I want to loop through.';
```

To loop through this, I know that a For-In would work and the syntax would be...

```
for (var newString in someString) {
someString[newString] = console.log(someString[newString]);
};
```

It works but it looks through each individual letter, top to bottom. I'd rather just have the words in each sentence, not the letters themselves. What specifically would work to handle the kind of result I would like?

Thanks in advance, everyone.

Comment: Then [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it into array first

Comment: You'll need to split the string into an array of words and loop over the array of words.

Comment: Good seeing some more people getting into JS! 
One way of doing this could be to split the string using `string.split()`. You can find some data on that here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Then simply iterate over the created array. :)

Comment: First thing: strings are not objects.

Comment: So there's no way to actually keep the object as an object to loop through it in the way I want to? I have to change it into an array with the split method at all times in this scenario??? Edit: towards Pointy. Yes, that's mostly true. You can change that whole rule with a constructor function but either way I do understand where you're coming from.

Comment: A string is not an object in the first place; it's a primitive value. You can construct a String instance, but that still does not give access to the contents of the string (the sequence of characters) as your code expects. The "parts" of a string are those characters, not words or  any other grammatical construct.

Comment: As @Pointy pointed out (no pun intended) a string isn't really an object. You might have confused it with an array of characters or something similar as you are iterating over it much as you would an array. :)

Comment: @KennethMcAusland The space `' '` character is just the same as all the other characters, so you must identify it in one way or another. Splitting by this character seems to me like a good way of doing what you're trying to do

Comment: Pointy, go into that. What is the real difference between primitive values vs objects. Also, I understand that arrays are a 'special type' of object when using 'typeof'.

Comment: What I think pointy is trying to mention here is that there is a difference between primitive **data types** and objects. An object is a **data type** but a primitive data type isn't an object, though primitive types can be part of an object. 

Have a read here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment there are a few different ways you can do this.

I'd prefer using **[String.Split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)** which basically splits a string on an delimiter such as `" "` into an array of strings. Then you iterate over the created array using a `for of` loop.

```
let someString = 'This is a string object I want to loop through.'; // use let, not var!

for (let word of someString.split(" ")) {
    console.log(word);
}
```

I hope that solved it for you! :)

Comment: Yes, it did and thank you geostocker. Why did you use let instead of var? Sorry for the questions but I've never seen that before.

Comment: @KennethMcAusland It has to do with the current trends and JavaScript pushing into ES6 (EcmaScript 6). Do a quick search online and you'll find some good resources on the changes. It's basically syntactical changes that slowly and surely will be adopted more and more by the community. 

Keep at it, man! :)